# CMake: Where to install FooBarConfig.cmake and FooBarConfigVersion.cmake?

Tags: installation, cmake

Let be a library A that I compile with CMake. I also want to distribute it via a package (e.g. RPM).

Where should my package install the files AConfig.cmake and AConfigVersion.cmake ?

In /usr/share/cmake/Modules on Linux ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find what you need here:

http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Packaging

With the relevant portion of the text:

> Consider a project "Foo" that installs the following files:
>
> - `<prefix>/include/foo-1.2/foo.h`
> - `<prefix>/lib/foo-1.2/libfoo.a`
>
> It may also provide a CMake package configuration file
>
> - `<prefix>/lib/foo-1.2/foo-config.cmake`

The config files need the be in your install tree. Only the `FindXXX.cmake` file should go in the modules directory.

Comment: Ok I see. I was aware only of another tutorial that was a lot more vague. Thank you for this one. What is surprising, is that basically CMake accesses the config file in the installation location and uses it to know where to look for includes and libraries which are in the installation location. It doesn't seem logical.

Comment: @Barth Yeah, some design choices in CMake seem strange from time to time.