# What is the location to install .cmake extension files in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, cmake

I am working on various projects, some of which offer a .cmake extension which I want to install whenever the development package of the project is installed on your Ubuntu system.

The modules of cmake 2.8 are saved under

```
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/...
```

and I thought that was were I would want to install my own extensions (knowing that it would break once we go to cmake-3.0).

However, there seems to be another location where packages install their own extensions:

```
/usr/share/cmake/<project-name>/...
```

Is there a place where I could find documentation about this? So far my searches on Google have not pointed me in the right direction...

I have found the following answer, but that seems to be specific to cmake and not Ubuntu:

[CMake: Where to install FooBarConfig.cmake and FooBarConfigVersion.cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946622/cmake-where-to-install-foobarconfig-cmake-and-foobarconfigversion-cmake)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the CMake package configuration mechanism, which you mentioned in your question.

Imaging you have the following CMake files:

```
SomeProjectConfig.cmake
SomeProjectConfigVersion.cmake
SomeProjectExtensions.cmake
```

The `SomeProjectConfig.cmake` and `SomeProjectConfigVersion.cmake` can be generated by [CMakePackageConfigHelpers module](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/CMakePackageConfigHelpers.html).

You can install them into `/usr/share/cmake/SomeProject/` folder, for example. For full list of default paths used by CMake see [find_package documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/find_package.html).

In your `SomeProjectConfig.cmake` you can include the `SomeProjectExtensions.cmake` file or expand `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` variable to let user include the CMake script:

```
# SomeProjectConfig.cmake
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
set(SOME_PROJECT_SOME_VAR "...")
function(some_project_func)
    ...
endfunction()
```

Now your users might use your CMake scripts via `find_package`:

```
# User CMakeLists.txt
find_package(SomeProject REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "SOME_PROJECT_SOME_VAR = ${SOME_PROJECT_SOME_VAR}")
some_project_func()
include(SomeProjectExtensions)
```